# how to use statistics functions like avg, max and so on in sparkr

Tags: function, max, average, min, sparkr

I am using SparkR. Now I have problems with using statistics functions like avg, max and so on. Firstly, I read a json file like:

```
> a <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/fengchen/mine/mydata/try.json", "json")
```

Then, a is a dataframe in spark instead of a normal R dataframe. I am trying some functions from https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/R/  But when I use the functions like avg, max, min, I got nothing. On RStudio, it shows like:

```
> avg(aa$pipelat)
Column avg(pipelat)
```

So, how can I show or know the value of the functions?
BTW, the functions the parameters of which are dataframe work fine, such as agg. I just do not know how to deal with the functions the parameters of which are columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head()` only returns the first rows of the resulting DataFrame.
`rdf <- collect(sdf)`
converts a distributed Spark DataFrame into a local R data.frame that can be displayed.

So, for the example in your second post:
`collect(selectExpr(df,"max(laidyear)","min(type)"))`
... will return the results for all values of laidyear, not not just the first 6 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it. The following format works.

```
head(selectExpr(df,"max(laidyear)","min(type)"))
```